# QSemaphore producer consumer problem

Tags: qt

This is more or less Qt's example with some small changes.

The output is PcPcPcPc...etc.  I don't understand why.

Namely, I am confused about how sProducer.acquire(256); works.  I believe I understand how sProducer.acquire(1); works. It doesn't make sense to me to acquire anything more than 1 because I don't see how acquiring more than 1 makes any difference logically.  Could someone explain this?  On the surface, writing 1 byte and reading 1 byte doesn't seem very efficient due to semaphore overhead...but acquiring more resources doesn't seem to make a performance difference nor does the code make sense.

Logically I think both the acquire and release have to have the same number (whatever that number is). But how can I modify this code so I can acquire more (say 256) and thus reduce semaphore overhead?  The code bellow just doesn't make sense to me when acquire and release is not 1.

```
#include <QtCore>
#include <iostream>
#include <QTextStream>

//Global variables.
QTextStream out(stdout);
QTextStream in(stdin);

const int DataSize = 1024; 
const int BufferSize = 512;
char buffer[BufferSize];    

QSemaphore sProducer(BufferSize);
QSemaphore sConsumer(0);
//-----------------------------

class Producer : public QThread
{
public:
    void run();
};

void Producer::run()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < DataSize; ++i) {
        sProducer.acquire(256);
        buffer[i % BufferSize] = 'P';
        sConsumer.release(256);
    }
}

class Consumer : public QThread
{
public:
    void run();
};

void Consumer::run()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < DataSize; ++i) {
        sConsumer.acquire(256);
        std::cerr << buffer[i % BufferSize];
        out << "c";
        out.flush();
        sProducer.release(256);
    }
    std::cerr << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    Producer producer;
    Consumer consumer;
    producer.start();
    consumer.start();
    producer.wait();
    consumer.wait();

    in.readLine();  //so i can read console text.
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is only one producer and one consumer, they can move freely their own private cursor, their `i` variable, of the amount of bytes they want, as long as there is enough room to do that (something higher that 256 on both sides with a 512 buffer would cause a deadlock).

Basically, when a thread successfully acquire 256 bytes, it means it can safely read or write these 256 bytes in one single operation, so you just have to put another loop inside the acquire/release block to handle that number of bytes.

For the producer:

```
void Producer::run()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < DataSize; ++i) {
        const int blockSize = 256;
        sProducer.acquire(blockSize);
        for(int j = 0; j < blockSize; ++i, ++j) {
            buffer[i % BufferSize] = 'P';
        }
        sConsumer.release(blockSize);
    }
}
```

And for the consumer

```
void Consumer::run()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < DataSize; ++i) {
        const int blockSize = 128;
        sConsumer.acquire(blockSize);
        for(int j = 0; j < blockSize; ++i, ++j) {
            std::cerr << buffer[i % BufferSize];
            out << "c";
            out.flush();
        }
        sProducer.release(blockSize);
    }
    std::cerr << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I c now the concept behind n for semaphores. I noticed you made the producer 256 and the consumer 128. I traced this and it gives the producer an early lead. After the buffer gets filled once, the procurer still maintains a lead but after that, every second run it is blocked while consumer catches up enough. The consumer is never blocked. I'm just wondering why you made the consumer use half the blocksize of he producer. Wouldn't giving them the same blocksize be more efficient (equal read and write rate)?  If one is slowed down by the OS, the other would be blocked anyway, no?

Comment: The `blockSize` is not about efficiency, but about what a producer/consumer could produce/consume in a single operation, in a real application. For example if you were reading data from a TCP socket, you would read as much as you can and put it in the ring buffer, the blockSize would be different for each iteration. And on the consumer side, you would read data for one message at a time, and the size of each of these messages could also be different.

Comment: I'm just wondering about your reason for making the consumer blocksize decidedly half of the producer.